# Why is my PowerDNS server not recursing compute.internal addresses?

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, powerdns

PowerDNS server with recursion enabled is resolving all addresses except for *.compute.internal

The server is running in AWS and has 10.30.0.2 as it's nameserver.

The following queries (testing the AWS Name Server) return the correct result:

```
dig ip-10-20-17-38.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal @10.30.0.2
dig www.google.com @10.30.0.2
```

Querying arbitrary public DNS entries directly against my DNS server is also successful:

```
dig www.google.com @127.0.0.1
dig www.serverfault.com @127.0.0.1
```

However querying compute.internal addresses fails with an NXDOMAIN status:

```
dig ip-10-20-17-38.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal @127.0.0.1

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> ip-10-20-17-38.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal @127.0.0.1
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 9324
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ip-10-20-17-38.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal.        IN A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       2087    IN      SOA     a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2018012401 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Jan 25 03:10:30 UTC 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 150
```

It looks like *.compute.internal addresses are not recursing to the default DNS server (10.30.0.2), but all other addresses are. What could explain this behaviour?

Comment: These addresses are not in the global DNS.

Comment: No, but they are known to the default DNS server (10.30.0.2).